# Not calling drawRect when setFrame is called

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit

I noticed that when a frame is set on a UIView, setNeedsDisplay is called by the UIView which in turn calls drawRect. I notice that this is the case even when I set the contentMode to Center, ScaleAspectFit, ScaleToFill. I would like drawRect to be called just once and not when the frame changes. Is this possible / is there a contentMode that enables this?

Answer (score 0):

It's none of your business when `drawRect:` is called. The fact that you are concerned about this is the problem. The system will call it when it needs to be called. Your job is to draw each time it is called. If you've implemented `drawRect:` correctly, that won't be any issue at all. It's a framework. It does its job, you do your job.

Comment: My drawRect is written to do the right thing. My concern is that this is CPU bound and I would like to reduce that it at all possible.

Comment: Do you understand about the iOS drawing system? Do you realize that it considers redrawing at the end of _every_ runloop? Do you know about CATransaction and what happens when each transaction is committed? There is not some kind of "burden" to drawing. The runtime knows when to draw. No drawing actually occurs while your code is running. Don't worry be happy.